# What does the invalid_preview_dimensions error means?

Tags: slack-api

I'm getting an `invalid_preview_dimensions` when calling  https://api.slack.com/methods/files.remote.add from my App.

It's not documented. Does anybody know what does it mean? https://api.slack.com/methods/files.remote.add#errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from Slack support:

> Preview images are required to be at least 800px wide by 400px tall.

So, the issues is fixed by uploading a larger image.